# Correct Javascript to get JSON info from Facebook Graph Query

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, graph

I am trying to get the URL for all the photos of a facebook page.

How do I get the 'source' URL for this query and JSON structure:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=19292868552%3Ffields%3Dalbums.fields(photos.fields(source))&version=v2.1
```

I am using this success callback from a JSONP request:

```
function(response) {
for (i = 0; i < **???response.albums.data.length???**; i++) {                
alert(**???response.albums.data[i].photos.data[i].source???**)
}
}
```

Can you help me find the right structure for the parts with the astericks? Because it has two [i]'s i think i'm getting confused..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have this in your head:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='workFromPage.js'></script>
```

Now on `workFromPage.js`

```
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
  if(pre)pre();
  if(!FB)reload();
  var photoURLs = [];
  // change userId
  // make sure you test for login and wrap around code below, if needed
  FB.api('/userId/albums',  function(resp){
    if(resp && !resp.error){
      for(var i in resp){
        FB.api('/'+resp[i].id+'/photos', function(r){
          if(r && !r.error){
            for(var n in r){
              photoURLs.push(r[n].source);
            }
            // access photoURLs here
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```